# Cython not able to compile

Tags: windows, mingw, cython

I am trying to compile following trivial code with Cython on Windows7 (64bit) and WinPython:

File testpy.py:

```
print("hello world from testpy.py file.")
```

File compile.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension("testpy",  ["testpy.py"]),
    #   ... all your modules that need be compiled ...
]
setup(
    name = 'My Program Name',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

I first give command to use mingw:

```
D:\myfolder> make_cython_use_mingw
cython has been set to use mingw32
to remove this, remove file "E:\WinPython\settings\pydistutils.cfg"
```

I then give command to compile:

```
D:\myfolder> python compile.py build_ext --inplace
```

The process starts but ends with following error:

```
running build_ext
skipping 'testpy.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'testpy' extension
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IE:\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\include -IE:\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\include -c testpy.c -o build
\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\testpy.o
In file included from E:\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\include/Python.h:68:0,
                 from testpy.c:4:
E:\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\include/pytime.h:122:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outsid
e of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
E:\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\include/pytime.h:127:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outsid
e of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
writing build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\testpy.cp36-win_amd64.def
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\testpy.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\testpy.cp36-win_amd64.def -LE:\Wi
nPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\libs -LE:\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\PCbuild\amd64 -lpython36 -o D:\myfolder\testpy.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
Cannot export PyInit_testpy: symbol not defined
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

Where  is the problem and how can it be solved?

Edit: 
On renaming py file as pyx as suggested by @ead in comments, it worked to create pyd file. However, on trying it gives following error:

```
D:\Myfolder>python -c "import Testpy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Why is this not a valid Win32 application?

My python version is as follows:

```
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

---

Edit: I found that I had mingw installed separately also (apart from part of winpython). I removed that and tried again. I am now getting following error:

```
python compile.py build_ext --inplace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compile.py", line 12, in <module>
    ext_modules = ext_modules
  File "E:\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "E:\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "E:\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "E:\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 186, in run
    _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
  File "E:\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 308, in run
    force=self.force)
  File "E:\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1031, in new_compiler
    return klass(None, dry_run, force)
  File "E:\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 282, in __init__
    CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)
  File "E:\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 126, in __init__
    if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

How can this be corrected?

Comment: Try to rename your file to "testpy.pyx" - pyx is the normal name for Cython extension. Maybe this *.py confusses distutils

Comment: Pl see edit in my question above.

Comment: Is this a "compile it with Python 2; try to use it with Python 3" problem? The reason I suspect that is that they have different names for the module initialisation function

Comment: I think Cython came with Winpython. Hence, proper Cython would have been installed. Even if it was installed with `pip install cython`, proper version would have been installed.

Comment: I have only one python installed, confirmed by command `where python`.